# How to make an exception throw?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function that translates a two-dimensional array into csv format. The function should work only with text and number, otherwise it displays an error. When I start the function, the check first goes on and the function completes. How can I make the function continue to work?

```
function arraysToCsv(data) {
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    let value = data[i];
    for(let j = 0; j < value.length; j++){
      if(typeof value[j] !== 'string' || typeof value[j] !== 'number')
        throw new Error('Unexpected value');
      let result = value[j].replace(/"/g, '""');
      if (result.search(/("|,|\n)/g) >= 0){
          result = '"' + result + '"';
      }
      return result.join(',') + '\n';
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on `How can I make the function continue to work?`

Comment: aka. where does it stop working?

Comment: after verification, the function shuts down. And it is necessary that, continued to work.

Comment: `if(value[j] && typeof value[j] !== 'string' || typeof value[j] !== 'number')` This can be re-written like that

Comment: @KunalMukherjee anyway, the function exits.

Comment: What is the error in the console being displayed ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee There is nothing in the console. The function exits with the message Unexpected value.

Comment: @mrdnk initially. when I run the check goes and stop.

Comment: Do console.log(typeof value[j]); and check the results

Comment: @mrdnk result: string, number, symbol, object

Comment: Just spotted the issue - it can’t be Not Sting or Not number, it’s !(typeof ‘string’ || typeof ‘number’) - nothing ever will be not both

Answer (score 1):

If your function has to work only number or string you insert into the if the continue statement.

if(typeof value[j] !== 'string' || typeof value[j] !== 'number')
                    continue;

If you want show the error message you can use the alert or you can write it in the console through the console.log, before the continue statement. I hope helped you.

Comment: if it is not a string or a number, the function should throw an error with a message Unexpected value

Comment: if you not handle the error, your script will be stopped. You have to handle the error, try this:
`function arraysToCsv(data) {
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    let value = data[i];
    for(let j = 0; j < value.length; j++){
      try{
  if(typeof value[j] !== 'string' || typeof value[j] !== 'number')
    throw new Error('Unexpected value');
  let result = value[j].replace(/"/g, '""');
  if (result.search(/("|,|\n)/g) >= 0){
   result = '"' + result + '"';
  }
  return result.join(',') + '\n';
  }catch(err){
   console.log(err.message);
  }
  }
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
function arraysToCsv(data) {
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    let value = data[i];
    for(let j = 0; j < value.length; j++){
      let type = typeof(value[j]);
      let isStringOrNumber = type === 'string' || type === 'number';
      if(!isStringOrNumber)
        throw new Error('Unexpected value');
      let result = value[j].replace(/"/g, '""');
      if (result.search(/("|,|\n)/g) >= 0){
          result = '"' + result + '"';
      }
      return result.join(',') + '\n';
  }
  }
}
```

Alternatively (use and)...

```
function arraysToCsv(data) {
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    let value = data[i];
    for(let j = 0; j < value.length; j++){
      let type = typeof(value[j]);
      let isNotStringOrNumber = type !== 'string' && type !== 'number';
      if(isNotStringOrNumber)
        throw new Error('Unexpected value');
      let result = value[j].replace(/"/g, '""');
      if (result.search(/("|,|\n)/g) >= 0){
          result = '"' + result + '"';
      }
      return result.join(',') + '\n';
  }
  }
}
```